# Symfony 4.2 Form is not submitted or not valid

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I followed the symfony 4.2 documentation, but it seems the form is not submitted...

I spent my whole sunday, but it seems a secret how does it works, in the logs I do not see any errors.

So start it. the config contains these settings:

```
framework:
    validation:
        email_validation_mode: 'html5'
        enable_annotations: true
```

Here the entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FeedbackRepository")
 */
class Feedback extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $email;
```

AS you can see I use the Assert annotations for the validations.

So here the formtype:

```
class FeedbackType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Feedback::class,
            // enable/disable CSRF protection for this form
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            // the name of the hidden HTML field that stores the token
            'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Maybe the problem with the token, but I do not know exactly.

Now let see the view:

```
 <form action="{{ path('feedback') }}" type="POST">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                            {{ form_label(feedback.name) }}
                            {{ form_widget(feedback.name) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                            {{ form_label(feedback.email) }}
                            {{ form_widget(feedback.email) }}
                        </div>
{{ form_widget(feedback._token) }}
```

Next, here the controller which get the request.

```
/**
 * @Route("/feedback", name="feedback", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function feedbackFormAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): JsonResponse
{
    $feedbackForm = new Feedback();

    $form = $this->createForm(FeedbackType::class, $feedbackForm);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    dump($request);
    dump($feedbackForm);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager->persist($feedbackForm);
        $entityManager->flush();
    } else {
        $errors = $this->getErrorsFromForm($form);
        dump($form);die;
        return new JsonResponse(['data' => ['result' => 'failed', 'errors' => $errors]]);
    }
    return new JsonResponse(['data' => ['result' => 'success']]);
}
```

The errors give me an empty array in Json format.
If I check the `dump($feedbackForm)` I see that the `submitted` property is false. and the `modeldata`, `viewdata` and `normdata` values are null... But how is this possible?

Dumping request:

```
query: ParameterBag {#16 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "feedback" => array:11 [▼
        "name" => "a"
        "email" => "a@a.a"
        "_token" => "NJHBv7NpwYlugFcU-sE0qoBEQkS38yhxOjbklkHu8j0"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I think, this is correct.

Comment: You don't have render the view with the same action [ if I really understand your logic here ]. So, handleRequest is not mapped with request of current action.

Answer (score 1):

You have not loaded the form data into the entity and trying to persist an empty new Feedback.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    // add line below
    $feedbackForm = $form->getData();

    $entityManager->persist($feedbackForm);
    $entityManager->flush();
} else { ...
```

Read carefully https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your FeedbackType, Controller action and the form view manually?
Remove all and use

```
php bin/console make:crud Feedback
```

This will generate operational files :-)

I think that using **form_row** is apropriate that using **form_widget**

Your Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/feedback", name="feedback", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function feedbackFormAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): JsonResponse
{
    $feedback = new Feedback();

    $form = $this->createForm(FeedbackType::class, $feedback);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->persist($feedbackForm);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return new JsonResponse(['data' => ['result' => 'success']]);
        }
        else {
            $errors = $this->getErrorsFromForm($form);
            return new JsonResponse(['data' => ['result' => 'failed', 'errors' => $errors]]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('path_to_your_feed_back.html.twig', [
        'feedback' => $feedback,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Your form.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST', 'attr' : {'class' : 'formFeedback'}}) }}
    <div class="input-field">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
        {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Yes I used the Crud operation, and I modified to use the json response and custom form_widgets.

Comment: I think that using **form_row** is apropriate that using **form_widget**

`{{ form_start(feedback, {'method': 'POST', 'attr' : {'class' : 'formFeedback'}}) }}
    <div class="input-field">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        {{ form_row(feedback.name) }}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
        {{ form_row(feedback.email) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(feedback) }}`

Comment: I have edited my answer! I don't see where do your send the generated feedback form from the controller to your form  view!